Object resize animation without stretching the bevel
If I add a resize animation to a cube with beveled edges, the bevel stretches and deforms. I've tried both the Ctrl+B shortcut and using the Bevel modifier on a Vertex Group, but both methods produce the same result. Applying scale didn't help in this case. Is there a solution for this?

Hello and welcome to BSE. yeah it won't work if you stretch the scale of the object. You have to stretch the mesh itself. So maybe try using Shape Key animation instead?

Yeah you cannot alter the scale as it will stretch the entire object. You will have to stretch or elongate the mesh itself within the object. Maybe try using Shape Keys instead. You can animate the Shape Key Value as well.

